# how do i attach and detach calendar or virtual keybaord on textbox based on data in React

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, reactjs, reactjs-flux

i am using react and flux and as soon as i update my store based on my data react should attach calendar or time-picker or numpad etc.

```
data.map(function(mydata, index) {
 if(mydata === 'Integer'){
     var inputBox = (<input className="center-block" type="text" onClick={attachNumpad.bind(this, 'checklist_field'+index1+ "-" + index)} />)
 }else if(mydata =='Date'){
     var inputBox = (<input className="center-block" type="text" onClick={attachCalendar.bind(this, 'checklist_field'+index1+ "-" + index)} />)
 }else if(mydata == 'String'){
     var inputBox = (<input className="center-block" type="text" onClick={attachKeybaord.bind(this, 'checklist_field'+index1+ "-" + index)} />)
 }
})();
```

Function to attach numpad or keyabord etc

```
function attachDateTime(id, toggleTime){   
   $('#'+id).datetimepicker({timepicker:toggleTime}).datetimepicker("show");  
}
function attachKeybaord(id, toggleTime){   
   $('#'+id).keyboard();  
}
```

react is not updating it attach keyboard for the first time then if i change data it doesnt attach numpad 
Help Please